# Pipe output (*.jpg file) of one command to another with CMD. Multiple command in MozJPEG

Tags: batch-file, cmd, jpeg, mozjpeg

How can I get Windows CMD to understand this type of things, what I have in bash:

```
cjpeg /jpg/image.jpg | jpegtran -optimize > result/jpg/image.jpg
```

I want to pipe the output of one MozJPEG command into another.

P.S.

*Before I used 'temp' folder in my script.*

```
cjpeg -quality 80 /jpg/image.jpg > /temp/image.jpg
jpegtran -optimize /temp/image.jpg > /result/jpg/image.jpg
```

*Run first command - save result in temp. After this, take file from 'temp' and pass it into second command - save final result.
But it creates unnecessary actions and garbage in folders :(*

Will be appreciated for any help and advices!

Comment: The Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` is designed to execute internal commands of `cmd.exe` and executables and process text files. It is not designed for processing binary data. It might work to use `cjpeg -quality 80 "C:\Folder Path\jpg\image.jpg" | jpegtran -optimize -outfile "C:\Folder Path\result\jpg\image.jpg"`, but I have myself never used `COMMAND.COM` or `cmd.exe` to pipe binary data output by one executable to __STDOUT__ to the __STDIN__ if another executable. I don't know if that data redirection works in this case with binary data.

Comment: @Mofi WOW! It is work. I wasted whole day looking for answer... Thank you so much!